# Export Div in React into PDF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

How can i export this barcode into a PDF file?

Pls check my codesandbox here

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-https-mib1n?file=/src/App.js)

```
export default function App() {
  const openPDF = () => {};

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => openPDF()}>
        Generate Barcode
      </Button>
      <Barcode value={"#freger"} height={60} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the time to prototype a solution in your sandbox:
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-joliot-57gdk?file=/src/App.js)

Basically you get a `ref` to the `svg` element of the barcode. Then you export a PDF with `svg2pdf.js`.

But bear in mind that using refs in this way relies on the implementation of `react-barcode`. So if you want a more robust solution, you could use `jsbarcode` itself.